# how to upload files from one server to another using move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, redhat

I have built a system where my application is running in one server and my database is running in another server. So when I try to upload files, it works fine in the local machine but when I change the location to the other server, it gives the following errors in the error_log file. I have set the ownership of the upload file to apache still it is not working in the remote server.

Following is my php code for file upload...

```
<?php
$name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
//echo $name;
$size=$_FILES['file']['size'];
$type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
$tmpname=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
echo $tmpname;
$error=$_FILES['file']['error'];
if(isset($name)){
    if(!empty($name)){
        //echo 'ok';
        $location="http://xx.xx.xx.xx/upload/";
        move_uploaded_file($tmpname,$location.$name);
        echo "uploaded";
    }

else 
echo "please choose a file";    
}
?>
```

and following is the php warning.....

PHP Warning: move_uploaded_file(http://xx.xx.xx.xx/upload/sentence005.TextGrid):
        failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in ..
        PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/php4kM8Qi'
        to 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx/upload/sentence005.TextGrid'

Comment: You cannot use this solution.You should move file with ftp account

Comment: give your file path from root folder don't use "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/upload/sentence005.TextGrid" use "./upload/sentence005.TextGrid"

Comment: @Chris I was just thinking the same

Comment: @HaRsH: i din get what u mean?? If i dont give the address,how php it will come to khow in which server it has to upload????

Comment: @user3487726 what ever error you got by of using this way you can solve but as other say you are not able to transfer file from one to other by using your code ..

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you cannot use move_uploaded_file() to upload files to a remote location. Use ftp as the other guy mentioned. PHP supports ftp... look into it.

Comment: This is how you'd do it:

1. Use move_uploaded_file() to upload the file locally (temporarily).
2. Use FTP functions to send the local file to the other server.
3. Use unlink() to delete the temporary file from local.

Comment: Once the file has been FTP'd to the other server you mean?

Comment: Well once you've moved the uploaded file to your server, then FTP'd it across to the other server you'll know where it's gone because you would of supplied the FTP function with a URL to where the file is going. If you need to supply a link on your webpage to where the file has been FTP'd to then use the URL you gave to the FTP function. Hope that helps.